# Use the same color definition in \setbeamercolor and \usecolortheme

Tags: beamer, color

In a Beamer document I have

```
% ...
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0.0,0.2}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=darkred}
\usecolortheme[darkred]{structure}
% ...
```

and when I compile with XeLaTeX I get this error

```
ERROR: Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `beamer@structure@color'.
```

associated with the `\usercolortheme` macro.

Of course I could do

```
\usecolortheme[RGB=135,0,51]{structure}
```

but I'd like to know if it possible to

1. either use directly `darkred` in the specification of a `colortheme`
2. or define `darkred` differently, so that it can be used in both ways,

because I'd like to use and possibly change a single definition.

Comment: Did you already try with `\usecolortheme[named=darkred]{structure}`? (See also: page 179 of the `beamer` manual.)

Comment: No, I had not tried... Thank you very much, that's it!  If you have the time please make this an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a previously named color in `\usecolortheme`, you can use its optional argument as folows:

```
\usecolortheme[named=darkred]{structure}
```

From the `beamer` manual:

[image]